# Hierarchical Logistic regression

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I have performed a hierarchical logistic regression with four steps, with various health risk variables including cigarette smoking. How do I interpret a change in odds ratio in  step 1  for cigarette smoking  OR 5.75 to that in step 2 OR 3.98 while adding in other risk behaviors like use of alcohol and drugs. All odds are significant throughout the models.

Answer (score 2):

OR=5.75 in step 1 means that smokres have 5.75 as large risk (or 4.75 times larger risk) as non-smokers. Can we say that smoking increases risk 4.75 times? Not necessarily. Smoking can be related to other risk factors. Smokers use peppermint chewing gum a lot, what if chewing peppermint gum is also a risk factor? If we do not include it in model we can not separate risk due to smoking from risk due to chewing gum. These two risks combine to give OR=5.75.

Adding "chewing gum" variable to model allows for separation of those two risks. After doing this OR for smoking will probably drop. We can say that this new OR is free from chewing gum risk (more elegantly: it is "adjusted to chewing gum")

OR=3.98 in step 2 means that risk behaviors, that you added, were "included" in smoking's OR. So, 4.75 times increase found in step 1 was not only due to smoking. Some part of it was related to risk behaviors added in step 2. And, after removing them, risk increase due to smoking is 2.98 times.

Comment: I think that should be 5.75 *as large*, not 5.75 times *larger*.

Comment: Can you explain why? My english is not perfect :)

Comment: Larger is wrong here. "More likely" is better.

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło Sure! Here goes: 20 is twice *as large as* 10. 30 is *two times larger than* 10, because it is 10 + (10 * 2).

Comment: @mkt Thanks for english classes :) I've edited my post

Comment: @SmallChess I've edited my post. Now it's "5.75 as large risk".

Comment: @mkt Is "5.75 times increase" OK?

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło No, the increase is 4.75 times, because the baseline is 1 (since OR = 1 is no change).

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło (+1) It may help to think of it like this: if somebody says that their weight increased by 100%, you would understand that it doubled (100 + 100). And if they said that their weight was 200% of the earlier weight, it would still mean that it doubled (100 * 2). However, if their weight *increased* by 200%, it would have tripled (100 + 200).

Comment: @mkt I know that. Maths is not my problem. It's English :)

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło Yes, I think your explanations are generally clear. Happy to help with the small English suggestion.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7894/31475. I strongly advise not using "a 4.75 times larger risk" to mean "5.75 times as large a risk", or "increases risk 4.75 times" to mean "increases risk by a factor of 5.75", if you want to be understood as well as logically correct.

Comment: And about the change in variance on adding an extra variable into each step, The Nagelkerke R2 value for the model/step with demographic variables alone in step 1 was 0.119, meaning 11.9%, and the corresponding step adding in other IVs it becomes 0.403, How do we explain the low R2 in model 1 and the 51% increase in R2 in the model 2 where we added 3 important IVs related to different forms of tobacco use.